# ¿Cómo puedo crear una variable en la que se pueda acceder desde diferentes ventanas?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo variables en común las cuales siempre estoy mandando entre ventanas de esta forma :

```
public Window1(int x)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

y las llama así,

```
Window1 w = new Window1(X);
```

es algo que siempre voy a necesitar tanto modificar como utilizar y no se que es mejor dejarlo así o crear una especie de clase que lleve eso no tengo muy claro que debo hacer para mejorarlo

dejo una imagen para que se pueda entender aún mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `C#` el concepto de variables globales al estilo de otros lenguajes no existe, lo que si podrías hacer eventualmente, es crear un clase estática que englobe todas tus variables globales:

```
public static class GlobalVars {

  public static int Var1 = 9;
  
}
```

Puedes acceder a los miembros de la clase tanto para reasignar valores como para recuperarlos:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("El valor de Var1 es: {0}", GlobalVars.Var1));
```

Comment: Eso es lo que había pensado desde un principio pero no estaba seguro de que fuese la mejor forma de hacerlo

Answer (score 3):

Se puede hacer de diferentes formas, la forma que comentas es la herencia.

1. tiene que hacer una variable global en tu Form principal.

```
public int NumeroGlobal;
```

2. Generas un Form y en el contructor agregas el parámetro que vas a recibir, recuerda que tiene que ser el mismo tipo de variable que mandaras en este caso int.

```
public Form2(int NumeroRecibido)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

3. Ahora debe generar de igual forma una variable global en ese formulario para poder usarlo en cualquier momento mientras esté abierto el módulo.

```
private int _NumeroRecibido;
```

4. En el constructor solo agregas la asignación de la variable para almacenarlo.

```
public Form2(int NumeroRecibido)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _NumeroRecibido = NumeroRecibido;
}
```

5. En el evento que usaras para llamar un Form lo generas de la siguiente forma

```
Form2 w = new Form2(NumeroGlobal);
Form2.Show();
```

Y listo puede agregar un punto de interrupción para ver el paso a paso, de igual forma recuerda darle valor a tu variable `NumeroGlobal` de lo contrario siempre mandaras nulo.

Los otro módulos que van a heredar el parámetro tiene que hacer lo mismo del paso 2 al 4.

Espero te sirva amigo